# How to extract debug information from a DOS executable compiled with Watcom C/C++?

Tags: c, debugging-symbols, dos-exe

I have a DOS executable which has been compiled with Watcom C/C++ 10.0.

That EXE has debug symbols inside. I was wondering if there is any tool that allow to dump or extract that debug information (eg : to a text file) I'm looking to something like TDUMP for Borland C/C++ compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenWatcom includes the `wdump` utility which can dump the debug info (if it's present).

Comment: It worked! Thanks. I had to wrote `wdump -Dx somefile.exe`to get what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This web site: `http://www.exphys.jku.at/Skripten/PK_PROG/Watcom.pdf`

is a PDF that (step by step) explains how to debug such files.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to debug the file, only to dump the actual debug information in order to re-import it to IDA.

Comment: the link is broken